# In rails 3.2.8 how do you create with one of your variables is another Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models, `State` and `Office`.

```
Office has_one State
Office name: string, city: string, state: State

State belongs_to Office 
State name: string, Abbrv: string
```

I'm new to ruby, so I'm figuring out how this works. I would think to create an `Office` would be:

```
Office.create( name: 'The Building', city: 'Kansas', state: State.first )
```

When I look at whats saved I get `state: nil`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `State.first` return in the console?

Comment: what does State.first return?  Also do you really need office to have one state?  Couldn't it just be a normal field?

Comment: If this app is on the public internet, I'd patch it to the current version of Rails, now 3.2.13, as these address [serious vulnerabilities](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/3/18/SEC-ANN-Rails-3-2-13-3-1-12-and-2-3-18-have-been-released/) that have been exploited in the wild. Have your app tested with [GemCanary](https://gemcanary.com/) or another service to be safe.

Comment: I'm developing, so everything is done locally. In console I hit State.first and get the one record to show. When I create Office passing State.first as state I get State(#55....) expected, FixNum(#55....)

Comment: As for the normal field, yea, could go either way, but I'm just trying to teach myself how to use associations so using this simple example so I can have an understanding when I get into more complex models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your DB table uses `:state` instead of `:state_id`. Office should have a column in the DB called `:state_id`.

When you call save on the Office, it will save the id of the state. When you call `office.state` it will automagically fetch the state from the DB. When you call `office.save` it will also save the attached `state` if it has not yet persisted to the DB.

Comment: Checked DB and it does have the state_id inside Office table. What do you think about the error I got?

Comment: Oh, I think I got it backwards. What if you swap the `has_one` and `belongs_to` so that Office `belongs_to` State and vice-versa?

Comment: Looks like setting belongs_to :state worked without _has_one, is this ok logically?

Comment: @g00n3r without the `has_one` on the State, you won't be able to call `state.office`. Your earlier problem was that the `belongs_to` should be on the model which has the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify..you create associations between models and relationships between tables.
To create one-to-one association you set `has_one``:name_of_the_child_model`, or `belongs_to` `:name_of_the_parent_model`, respectively. In your example:
class Office < ActiveRecord::Base 
attr_accessible :name, :city

has_one :state 
end

class State < ActiveRecord::Base 
attr_accessible :name, :abbrv

belongs_to :office 
end

After that you create relationship between corresponding tables. You do that by setting primary key of a parent table(Office model) as a new field/column in the child table(State model), so that State model looks like:

class State < ActiveRecord::Base 
attr_accessible :name, :abbrv, :office_id

belongs_to :office 
end

To instantiate and save a new State object on Office object in one step, you can use `.create_modelname(attributes={})`method: 
 
`office = Office.find(id)`
`office.create_state({name: "state_name", abbr: "abbrv"})`.

You got `nil` because `State.first` was just trying to read first object from the states table which you did not previously wrote in.